# Jmeter cookie manager not renewing cookie with each loop

Tags: jmeter, prometheus, metrics

I am fairly new to jmeter and currently I am using jmeter to create a test plan with Prometheus plugin, we have various endpoints that needs to be probed, our application use a cookie that refreshes every day so the cookie value changes likewise. Once the jmeter runs on the host, it gives 200 response code but after a day, when the cookie refreshes, we start seeing 401s for all the endpoints, my guess is the cookie is not being generated properly. I am using HTTP cookie manager in the jmeter which supposedly gets the cookie automatically, and I also have selected clear cookie each iteration but it doesn’t seem to work.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Cookie Manager does really clear cookies but it applies only to [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration, other [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) like [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) won't trigger cookies renewal.

You can check what exactly is happening by [enabling debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the HTTP Cookie Manager: add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

and upon JMeter restart the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) will contain information regarding incoming and outgoing cookies.

It's also possible to force clear cookies, it can be done by adding a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the very first HTTP Request sampler and putting the following code into "Script" area:

```
sampler.getCookieManager().clear()
```